# matrix date field output

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic

I'm having some trouble getting a matrix field to output a date cell correctly.

I am running EE 2.5.2, Matrix 2.4.1.

When I put the following code into my template:

```
{legislator_labi_score limit="1" orderby="score_date" sort="desc"}
<strong>LABI Score: {score_number}%</strong><br />
<small>(as of {scoreEditDate format="%m/%d/%Y"})</small><br />
{/legislator_labi_score}
```

It outputs like this:

```
(as of {scoreEditDate format="%m/%d/%Y"})
```

If I just put the field with no formatting info at all it outputs like this:

```
(as of June 10,2012)
```

which isn't bad, but it isn't what I wanted. Can you tell me what the problem might be? I saw a post from Get Satisfaction that had this issue, but they upgraded to 2.4.1 and it fixed the issue. I'm running 2.4.1 and I'm still having the problem.

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: Hey Brian - the first thing to do is upgrade to Matrix 2.5.3 - lots of updates and this may be fixed in the course of those updates.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Per comment from add-on developer team member (Lisa), upgrading is the solution.